# making a torch on android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android

i am a hobbyist with no professional degree , trying to learn android programming there few codes I'm finding difficult to create .
I m trying to make a basic torch android app on android studio here are the codes:
package com.example.adityachhabra.mytorch;

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
        import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    private Camera cam1;
    Camera.Parameters params;
    private boolean isOn;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(); {
            @Override
          public void onclick (View v){
                  if (isOn) {
                        params = cam1.getParameters();
                        param }
                }}
```

unable to create "on click" on public void.
see the url/youtube - https://youtu.be/pj6tqD7IbZU

Comment: Hi aditya, welcome to Stack overflow! Please edit your post with including a description exactly what you are experiencing, so people don't need to open external videos. You don't need to include a personal introduction here, but you are very wellcome to write one on your personal profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6688439/aditya-chhabra

Answer (score 0):

you are unable to call onClick cause of isOn variable because the default value is false always, change this

```
private boolean isOn;
```

to

```
private boolean isOn = true;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!